# How can one assign an action to a user pressing on a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

In objective-c, how can I assign an action to the event of someone pressing on one of the UITableViewCells that have been instantiated in a UITableView controller? Basically, the overall action I'm trying to achieve is for a user to be able to click a UITableViewCell, which then opens up a new view controller that contains the information that corresponds to the ID of that UITableViewCell, specifically.

Comment: are you using segue ?

Comment: ...show code of what you tried thus-far...

Comment: It's fine, there's a working solution selected. Thanks for all your help, everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write below code in your FirstViewController.m file

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{

}
@end
@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableviewName.delegate = self;
    self.tableviewName.dataSource = self;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    SecoundViewController *secoundVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecoundVC”];
    secoundVC.cellId = @“pass your data here”; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secoundVC animated:YES];

}
```

Write below code in your SecoundViewController.h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *cellId;
```

Write below code in your SecoundViewController.m file

```
#import "SecoundViewController.h"

@interface SecoundViewController ()
{

}
@end
@implementation SecoundViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"cellId----%@",self.cellId);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //Perform segue here


}
```

Comment: I have this function implemented, currently. Are you saying that all I need to do is add the segue there and it'll be a unique segue for each tableviewcell? So, let's say I wanted to send a property of the tableviewcell to the next view, can I accomplish this through this method?

Answer (score 0):

In your DESTINATION (.h) view controller:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *idDetail;
```

Then in your ORIGIN view controller (where you have your table):

```
@property int idCell;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.idCell = indexPath.row
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailViewController" sender:sender];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailViewController"]) {
        SecondVC *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.idDetail = idCell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, both yours and the one above work.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a tap gesture recognizer when creating the cell in data source:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
    cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = ...
    if cell.gestureRecognizers.count == 0 {
        var recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: 
            #selector(handleCellTap(sender:)))
        recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }
}

func handleCellTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let viewCell = sender.view as? UITableViewCell else {
        return
    }
    ...
}
```

If your data source and controller have the same class, you can just `pushViewController` in `handleCellTap` function.

Using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not what you want, I think.

Sorry for possible typos, I haven't XCode now to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without using segues. Simply instantiate the view controller from storyboard and pass data(if needed) to any global params.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    Session *session = self.arrSessions[indexPath.row];
    ExampleViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ExampleViewController"];
    controller.selectedSession = session; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's similar to the one Rajesh posted. That reassures me that this is the correct method to use, from now on. I appreciate this a lot.